# Setting multiple value for select

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i set multiple values for multiple select. This is what i have tried so far in jquery. I looking for a jquery as well as pure js solution(just for my knowledge).

```
for(x in gList)
{
    $('#GList').val(gList[x]);
}
```

This is selecting only one and not all.

EDIT: I found another solution in jquery . Hope this too helps others. In the loop use

```
$("#GList option[value=" + gList[x] +"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

Comment: This is in the docs. http://api.jquery.com/val/ at `Example: Set a single select, a multiple select, checkboxes and a radio button .`.

Comment: Isn't your alternative solution a little too awkward and cumbersome? I'd suggest following docs guidelines

Comment: yes i know that's why i am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#GList').val(gList);
```

As per: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

as a side note, with:

```
for(x in gList){
    $('#GList').val(gList[x]);
}
```

You select the 1st item in `gList` then you select the 2nd, deselecting the 1st, and so on...